# Dynamically creating buttons in thymeleaf table

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I am generating a table, using thymeleaf, that represents a list of objects (Snacks).  Each snack has a number of votes associate with it .  I would like to have a button for each snack so a user can vote for it, increasing its vote count displayed then updated once a submit button is clicked

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Snacks</th>
        <th>Last Date Purchased</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
        <th>Up Vote</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr th:each="snack,iterStat : ${snacksuggested}">
        <td th:text="${snack.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${snack.lastPurchaseDate}"></td>
        <td th:text="${snack.votes}"></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default" th:id="${'voteBtn_'+(iterStat.count -1)}" th:text="${snack.name} +' Vote'">Up Vote</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

1. How do I reference a specific snack?
2. Where do I place the javascript function definition?
3. And how can I update the displayed vote count on button click?

PS. i am using Spring

Comment: You could add an initial extra cell to store the counter by row. The snack object doesnt have a id?

Comment: let me explain what i have so far in an edit to the question...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used **thymeleaf** on Spring. I have used jstl on jsp pages. So, I am explaining you from my point of view. First of all you should provide id's to every element that you are generating for accesibility from Javascript/Jquery.

So to answer your queries:

1. We will reference a snack using `class vote_button`. Same class will be applied to every snack.
2. You can place the jquery/javascript function at the end of your code inside script tags to make sure that the DOM has loaded before JQuery starts.
3. You can add a value to each button containing the `id`. Then on each click you can get that `id` and use that to reference the votecount.

   ```
     <tr th:each="snack,iterStat : ${snacksuggested}">
       <td th:text="${snack.name}" id="snackname_${iterStat.count-1}"></td>
       <td th:text="${snack.lastPurchaseDate} id="purchasedate_${iterStat.count-1}"></td>
       <td th:text="${snack.votes} id="votes_${iterStat.count-1}"></td>
       <td>
           <button class="btn btn-default vote_button" value="${'voteBtn_'+(iterStat.count -1)}" th:id="${'voteBtn_'+(iterStat.count -1)}" th:text="${snack.name} +' Vote'">Up Vote</button>
       </td>
     </tr>
   ```

After assigning ids to every element fo the table now it is time to write a Jquery/Javascript code. We will have to use a class to access different vote buttons.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".vote_button").on('click', function() {
          var id = $(this).val();
          var idArray = id.split('_');
          var voteId= idArray[1];
          var currentVal = $("#votes_"+voteId).html();
          $("#votes_"+voteId).html(currentVal+1);
    });
});
```

I encountered a similar scenario that you are facing and this is how I solved it. I hope it helps you.

It is not advisable to dynamically bind objects. What I did was that I gave the same class to every row `vote_button` and then apply this class to every dynamically created element. Every time the `votebutton` is clicked we can access the value of the button or the id of the button which is generated as `vote_id`(name separated by underscore and then id). By splitting this value we can get the `id` of the row we want to reference. We can access any value of the row by this `id` as the name of each `<td>` is `name_id`(like votes_1, snackname_1) as in each row the number after the underscore will be same and it is just the position of the row.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I like the idea behind your answer.  But...in reading your answer i realize how much i don't quite get.     1. I'm thinking of placing your script js class under the last  `</tr>` yes / no?    2.  How do I go about data binding with dynamically labelled object fields (ie snackname_1, snackname_2) maybe using a map?     3.  As you can tell i dont have much experience in front end dev, do you have any tutorial suggestions?

Comment: @JustinD 1. You can place the js code at the last of your HTML code. 2. It is not advisable to dynamically bind objects. What I did was that I gave the same class to every row `vote_button` and then apply this class to every dynamically created element. Every time the votebutton is clicked we can access the value of the button or the id of the button which is generated as `vote_id`. By splitting this value we can get the `id` of the row we want to reference. We can access any value of the row by this `id` as the name of each `<td>` is `name_id`. I will add this in the answer as well.